Figure not showing in github page
I am trying to set up my Homepage using github. I am using the academic webpage template and I was trying to add an image in about.md using the following code:
<figure class="inline end" markdown>
  ![](/images/knotSoliton.jpg){width=300 }
  <figcaption>David S. Hall, Amherst College, using code developed by Niles Johnson</figcaption>
</figure>

Instead, I am only getting the text
![](/images/knotSoliton.jpg){width=300 }

followed by the caption. I confirmed the path of the image by replacing the above code by just
![](/images/knotSoliton.jpg){width=300 }

which generates the image. The reason why I am using the first code is that I want to align the image to the right side and want similar results. I am not sure why it is not working as it clearly works in the given example. I would appreciate the help. Thanks in advance.
